# Jetpack compose snapshotFlow not working as expected

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was trying help a someone for this `snapshotFlow` then we both curious to know about this state issue. as we know `snapshotFlow` will help us to get the state values as flow.

**Problem**

```
 val (number1, setNumber1) = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
```

We have used this state like this above code. to set the value we used one more method. but for some reason this `snapshotFlow` was not working and in the `LaunchedEffect` we not able to collect those values. but then tried like this.

```
 val number2 = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
```

This was working as expected.
So what could be the problem. `number1Flow` wont collect the values when we change those but `number2Flow` will work.

did we miss something, let us know.

Also the full code.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Sample() {
    val (number1, setNumber1) = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    val number2 = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        snapshotFlow {
            number1
        }.collect {
            Log.v("number1Flow", it.toString())
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        snapshotFlow {
            number2.value
        }.collect {
            Log.v("number2Flow", it.toString())
        }
    }
    Text(
        text = "number1= $number1",
    )
    Text(
        text = "number2= ${number2.value}",
    )

    Button(onClick = {
        setNumber1(number1 + 1)
        number2.value += 1
    }) {
        Text(
            text = "increase the value",
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

SnapshotFlow works similarly to recomposition - it tracks reads of `State.value` to know when to emit. So for `snapshotFlow` to work, the value has to be read inside of the `snapshotFlow {}` block, which is not happening in the first case. In the second case, value is read inside of the block (that's obvious), when you do something like

```
val number by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
LaunchedEffect(Unit) { snapshotFlow { number } }
```

value is also read inside of the block, even though it's not directly visible because of the delegation. But the firs case is the same as doing this:

```
val number = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val numberValue = number.value
LaunchedEffect(Unit) { snapshotFlow { numberValue } }
```

Here, the value is read outside of the `snapshotFlow` block, which means that it doesn't know what changes to track.

This means that once you use the destructuring declaration to get the value and setValue, it's impossible to create `snapshotFlow` out of that. The only way would be to keep the `State` as well:

```
val numberState = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val (number, setNumber) = numberState
LaunchedEffect(Unit) { snapshotFlow { numberState.value } }
```

Comment: Bina, Thanks a lot. its pretty much clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `Flow` with

```
val number1Flow = snapshotFlow {
    number1
}
```

on each recomposition and the one you collect is the one that is assigned initially. If you log `number1Flow` or `number2Flow` instances you will see that on each button click new ones are created.

You can create Flow inside LaunchedEffect and collect same Flow with

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    snapshotFlow {
        number2.value
    }.collect {
       
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yes, you are right. i missed that part. let me update my code snippet. but `number2Flow` is collecting successfully and `number1Flow` not working for me.