# Why snapshotFlow is trigged with MutableState as property delegate?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, mutablestateof

I have a situation with the snapshotFlow recently when trying to observe changes from a MutableState. Here is the snippet

```
val searchQuery = mutableStateOf("")
snapshotFlow { searchQuery }.collectLatest {
               
}
```

But when the `searchQuery` changed, there was nothing happened in `collectLatest` block. It seems the `snapshotFlow` not find any changes from `searchQuery`. I guessed. Then I changed the searchQuery  declare to `var searchQuery by mutableStateOf("")`. The snapshotFlow works as expected. Can anyone explain me why? Really appreciate!

Comment: You need to read the mutableState in the `snapshotFlow`. For example `searchQuery.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76401073/8331157):

> SnapshotFlow works similarly to recomposition - it tracks reads of
> State.value to know when to emit. So for snapshotFlow to work, the
> value has to be read inside of the snapshotFlow {} block, which is not
> happening

With your current approach, the `snapshotFlow` doesn't know which changes to observe. When using the `by` keyword, `searchQuery.value` is implicitly called, and thus the `snaphotFlow` can detect the changes.

To solve this, please try

```
val searchQuery = mutableStateOf("")
snapshotFlow { searchQuery.value }.collectLatest {
    // ...      
}
```

or use the `by` keyword.

As the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) remains vague about how the approaches for declaring a MutableState differ, [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/rqdv5g/there_are_three_ways_to_declare_a_mutablestate/) summarizes the differences well.

Comment: What I'm wondering is that the Google documentation says we can listen to the status in 3 different ways. Why didn't they state the difference between them? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state?hl=en#state-in-composables

Comment: @ΓDΛ You have a valid point here. This has caused confusion and will cause further confusion. I found this Reddit Thread to properly explain the differences between the three approaches, which are bigger than you initially might think:
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/rqdv5g/there_are_three_ways_to_declare_a_mutablestate/

Comment: Yeah, I know the way to go now

Answer (score 1):

> snapshotFlow creates a Flow from observable Snapshot state. (e.g.
> state holders returned by mutableStateOf.)
>
> If the result of block is not equal to the previous result, the flow
> will emit that new result. (This behavior is similar to that of
> Flow.distinctUntilChanged.)

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotFlow.kt;drc=e17d836265f395ae589ba254c4efddd29a314ae3;l=75

With `val searchQuery = mutableStateOf("")` you are querying against instance of `MutableState`, which needs a new `MutableState` of `MutableState` to be collected.

The example below is only for demonstration purposes, unless explicitly required you don't need to store a `State` inside a `State`. We are collecting `state holder`of `MutableState` of query. If you assign new MutableState with button you will see that snapshotFlow collects new instance of MutableState

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun SnapshowFlowTest() {

    var query = remember {
        mutableStateOf(mutableStateOf(""))
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        snapshotFlow {
            query.value
        }
            .collect {
                println("State: $it, value: ${it.value}")
            }
    }

    Column {
        TextField(
            value = query.value.value,
            onValueChange = {
                query.value.value = it
            }
        )

        Button(
            onClick = {
                query.value = mutableStateOf("Default Value")
            }
        ) {
            Text("Set new MutableState")
        }
    }
}
```

With `var searchQuery by mutableStateOf("")` you are collecting the change in value of MutableState which is String.

Comment: Clean answer. Thanks. What I'm wondering is that the Google documentation says we can listen to the status in 3 different ways. Why didn't they state the difference between them? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state?hl=en#state-in-composables

Comment: Useful example! I have figured out the reason now